# Problem with web-scraping with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to web-scrape the who website(https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019) to find out the current death count of covid. I am having an issue, where it finds the element, but it is giving me a different content. My code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

WORLDWIDE_URL = "https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019"

page = requests.get(WORLDWIDE_URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

print(soup.find(id="confirmedDeaths"))
```

Instead of giving me a string, it doesn't give me anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not getting the results shown on the website is that these results are actually filled in by *JavaScript*-functions rather than being hardcoded into the website.
You'd get the same result if you just inspected the source-code (`Ctrl+U` in *Firefox*).

Using just `requests.get`, you just retrieve the source-code, where the information is not present.

Most of the time you'd be stuck now and would have to resort to solutions like using `selenium` to *render* the *Javascript* before accessing the information, but I found a different solution where you don't even need `BeautifulSoup`:

When looking at the source-code of the page, I found that the *JavaScript* that is responsible for setting these values is internally just calling a long and ugly URL to retrieve this information:

```
https://services.arcgis.com/5T5nSi527N4F7luB/arcgis/rest/services/COVID_19_Historic_cases_by_country_pt_v7_view/FeatureServer/0/query?where=CumCase+%3E+0&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&returnGeodetic=false&outFields=OBJECTID%2CISO_2_CODE%2CISO_3_CODE%2CADM0_NAME%2Cdate_epicrv%2CNewCase%2CCumCase%2CNewDeath%2CCumDeath&returnGeometry=true&featureEncoding=esriDefault&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=4326&datumTransformation=&applyVCSProjection=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnQueryGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=date_epicrv+desc&groupByFieldsForStatistics=date_epicrv&outStatistics=[{%27statisticType%27%3A+%27sum%27%2C+%27onStatisticField%27%3A+%27NewCase%27}%2C+{%27statisticType%27%3A+%27sum%27%2C+%27onStatisticField%27%3A+%27NewDeath%27}%2C+{%27statisticType%27%3A+%27sum%27%2C+%27onStatisticField%27%3A+%27CumCase%27}%2C+{%27statisticType%27%3A+%27sum%27%2C+%27onStatisticField%27%3A+%27CumDeath%27}%2C+{%27statisticType%27%3A+%27Count%27%2C+%27onStatisticField%27%3A+%27ADM0_NAME%27}]&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=pjson&token=
```

Calling this URL you can retrieve a *JSON*-dictionary containing all the information you need.

I decided to break this URL down to actually show you what's going on. Here's my full code:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib.parse

payload = {
    'where': 'CumCase+>+0',
    'objectIds': '',
    'time': '',
    'geometry': '',
    'geometryType': 'esriGeometryEnvelope',
    'inSR': '',
    'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects',
    'resultType': None,
    'distance': '0.0',
    'units': 'esriSRUnit_Meter',
    'returnGeodetic': False,
    'outFields': ','.join([
        'OBJECTID',
        'ISO_2_CODE',
        'ISO_3_CODE',
        'ADM0_NAME',
        'date_epicrv',
        'NewCase',
        'CumCase',
        'NewDeath',
        'CumDeath'
    ]),
    'returnGeometry': True,
    'featureEncoding': 'esriDefault',
    'multipatchOption': 'xyFootprint',
    'maxAllowableOffset': '',
    'geometryPrecision': '',
    'outSR': 4326,
    'datumTransformation': '',
    'applyVCSProjection': False,
    'returnIdsOnly': False,
    'returnUniqueIdsOnly': False,
    'returnCountOnly': False,
    'returnExtentOnly': False,
    'returnQueryGeometry': False,
    'returnDistinctValues': False,
    'cacheHint': False,
    'orderByFields': 'date_epicrv+desc',
    'groupByFieldsForStatistics': 'date_epicrv',
    'outStatistics': [
        {"statisticType": "sum", "onStatisticField": "NewCase"},
        {"statisticType": "sum", "onStatisticField": "NewDeath"},
        {"statisticType": "sum", "onStatisticField": "CumCase"},
        {"statisticType": "sum", "onStatisticField": "CumDeath"},
        {"statisticType": "Count", "onStatisticField": "ADM0_NAME"}
    ],
    'having': '',
    'resultOffset': '',
    'resultRecordCount': '',
    'returnZ': False,
    'returnM': False,
    'returnExceededLimitFeatures': True,
    'quantizationParameters': '',
    'sqlFormat': None,
    'f': 'pjson',
    'token': ''

}

payload_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload, safe='+[]{}')

# Replace True, False, None
payload_str = payload_str.replace('False', 'false')
payload_str = payload_str.replace('True', 'true')
payload_str = payload_str.replace('None', 'none')

r = requests.get(
    'https://services.arcgis.com/5T5nSi527N4F7luB/arcgis/rest/services/COVID_19_Historic_cases_by_country_pt_v7_view/FeatureServer/0/query',
    params=payload_str
)
json_dict = json.loads(r.text)

total_deaths = json_dict['features'][0]['attributes']['SUM_CumDeath']
```

---

### Explanation

1. In addition to just a plain URL, `requests.get` also accepts (among others) another paramter called `params`.
   In an URL-string, each element encapsulated between `&`-characters is actually a separate parameter passed along with the request. So instead of having just one long ugly string, you can call `requests.get` with the part of the URL before the `?`-sign and set `params` to a dictionary with all other parameters that need to be included as well.
   And as you can see from my answer, this makes it a lot easier to actually comprehend the request.

   If you look at my code though you'll realise that I actually didn't do that. **Why though?**
   When specifying the parameters through `params`, `requests` doesn't pass them along the request raw, it *encodes* them, i.e. `+` becomes `%2B` and so on.
   In this case the problem was that the server will return `404 not found` if requests encodes `+`-signs, so I needed another way to encode the *payload*, without losing the `+`-signs.
   The solution is to use `urllib.parse`, which accepts a string of characters to exclude from encoding, in this case I used the following string: `'+[]{}'`.
   So my solution was to pre-encode the payload and then pass the string to `requests` instead of the dictionary.
2. As the server is so picky, I also had to replace pythons `True`, `False` and `None` with lowercase-versions, else the parameters would not have been recognized.
3. When you make the request, you'll get a *JSON*-dict instead of the websites html-source, so you don't need `BeautifulSoup`, you just parse the json and are left with a simple Python `dict`.

   This dictionary might contain other information that could be useful to you. If you want to have a closer look at it, just open the long URL above in your browser. Most browser will automatically *"beautify"* JSON for you.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed explanation! You definitely helped me a lot.